# Swift app stops running after an error

Tags: ios, swift

My iOS app stops running after a run-time error occurs. I'm catching the error as an exception. I would like the app to continue running to the next steps after error handling. Any advises how to do this?

```
do {
    guard let ps: Element = try! docu.getElementById("product-name")! else { ide = "" }
    if ps != nil {
        ide = (try ps.text())
    }
} catch {
    print("error")
    ide = ""
}
```

Comment: Never use `!` in a `guard let`. It negates the whole point of the `guard`.

Comment: The `if ps != nil` is pointless since the `guard` guarantees that `ps` can't be `nil` (or optional).

Comment: And you can't handle exceptions, only errors that are thrown. Update your question with details about the exception you are getting and point out the exact line causing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overusing the `!` (force unwrap) symbol here. It does not deal gracefully with nil values, in fact, it crashes.

I think what you might want to be doing here is

```
guard
    let ps: Element = try? doc.getElementById("product-name"),
    let ide = try? ps.text()
    else {
    print("error")
    ide = ""
}
// ide is guaranteed to be valid here
...
```

Note how if you use `try?` you do not need to "catch" the error, it will simply return an optional value, `nil` if the call would raise an exception.

---

Alternatively you could simply

```
let ps: Element = try? doc.getElementById("product-name")
let ide = try? ps?.text()
// ide will be an optional value here
```

If you really don't want to `guard`/`if let`...

Comment: I will fix the code, but how do I prevent the app from stopping in ios simulator after an exception that occurs and is handled?

Comment: I think simply removing your `!`s will prevent that, it will be the cause of your crash (app stopping). However, for what you are trying to achieve, in my opinion you are better of simply using the optional notation as I have demonstrated.

Comment: is there a way to do this without using guard?

Comment: Absolutely, you could flip it round and use `if let`, but why would you not want to use `guard`? It's one of the most beautiful part of swift :)

Comment: I want to refer ide later in the code, so defining it with-in guard wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: By the way, I'm getting a compilation error with the above code. Value of optional type 'Element??' not unwrapped; did you mean to use 'try!' or chain with '?'?

Comment: @py_ios_dev Any variable declared via `guard let` is available after the `guard` statement.